# ValueError: ('Input data in `NumpyArrayIterator` should have rank 4. You passed an array with shape', (550, 8))

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I used stratified cross-validation in my model. I have datagen, which I will use to augment the train data.
Code snippet:

```
i=0
for train_index, val_index in skf.split(X_train, y_train):
    X_train_fold, X_val_fold = X_train[train_index], X_train[val_index]
    y_train_fold, y_val_fold = y_train[train_index], y_train[val_index]
    i = i+1;
    print("Fold:",i)
    features1 = extract_features(model1, X_train_fold)
    features2 = extract_features(model2, X_train_fold)

    # Concatenate the features
    features = Concatenate()([features1, features2])

    inputs = Input(shape=(features.shape[1],))
    x = Dense(32, activation='relu')(inputs)
    x = Dense(16, activation='relu')(x)
    predictions = Dense(4, activation='softmax')(x)

    ensemble_model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=predictions)

    print(X_val_fold.shape)
    print(y_train_fold.shape)
    print(features.shape)
    print(predictions.shape)
    # break

    ensemble_model.compile(optimizer = Adam(learning_rate=0.00001),loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',metrics=['accuracy'])
    ensemble_model.fit(datagen.flow(features, y_train_fold, batch_size=32), epochs=20, verbose=1)
```

error: `ValueError: ('Input data in` NumpyArrayIterator `should have rank 4. You passed an array with shape', (550, 8))`

when i use,

```
ensemble_model.fit(features, y_train_fold, batch_size=32, epochs=20, verbose=1)
```

the code works, but it doesn't work with `datagen.flow`
how to solve this? I can't ignore `datagen.flow` because my dataset is small and data augmentation is a must in this case.

Comment: It seems there is a problem with the dataset shape you have defined in the model and passing into model. Please check this similar [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67960945/keras-and-tensorflow-on-python-valueerror-input-data-in-numpyarrayiterator) with the same error which might help you to solve this issue.